# Will a collapsing black hole be ensured to be in eternal equilibrium at some point?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, gravitational-collapse

I'm just even if at all hobbyist in this matter.
I learned that stars will collapse at some point and go supernova or turn into black holes if not able to keep equilibrium.

But what happens in the blackhole state?

Is an black hole an eternal equilibrium?
Will blackholes at somepoint release a kind of supernva, aswell?

Or will it just keep collapsing to an infinite small size?

I can't rationaly imagine the last case, since all I physically know has a border in a way of some limits.

So I can't imagine their will be a state in which a black hole with all the mass contained will be smaller as the smallest element that could exist in it, while emphirical all I know about it sounds like, thats what it were going to do.

So what of this will be the case?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195481/are-black-holes-eternal http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168769/eternal-black-holes-and-hawking-radiation

Answer (score 1):

According to RG isolated, yes the singularity is infinite small size:
There can't be an equilibrium, for the sunk of space itself prevent any reaction force to counterbalance the collapse.

Now at this scale and energy, quantum mecanics can't be ignored, and there is indetermination principle, for a start.
The problem is that for now nobody knows how to knit these 2 physics together, and it's one of the main challenges of nowadays physics.

Anyway, don't expect to have intuitions of what occurs inside a BH.
A neutron star is the limit of our "not-too-far-to-familiar" intuition, and is already strange. Inside the black hole, RG-wise time freeze and space flow, space is so curved that volume could be inifinite. Classical-particle-wise (without QM) in the singularity no system could exist because you need 2-ways force exchanges.